# capturing another activity's screen in android

Tags: android, service, screen, android-activity, capture

is it possible to have a service (A) which will launch an activity (B) and then periodically capture B's screen?

also, is it possible to send onTouch events from A to B?

basically, i'd like to make a bot which would use an application so i don't have to.

i guess it's not possible but had to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that across `Activity`s but you could create a view that held the `Activity` that you want to automate.  Then periodically you can grab the `ViewDecorator` and do some processing on it and then inject touch events.

Comment: Ummm...really? I'm unconvinced that's even possible within your own application, and I am inferring that that OP as interested in controlling another application.

Comment: yes, i'm interested in controlling another activity which is not mine. don't have the source code for it or anything.

btw, can't find anything about ViewDecorator in android.

Answer (score 0):

Screen captures of apps which are not the current app are prevented in Android devices due to security considerations.
As far as I know up until Android 4.3 you can only do this in these scenarios:

- Your device is rooted
- Your app is signed with the same signature of the system (Google apps)
- With adb (debug environment): your device is connected via USB to a PC which is running adb shell commands, or either the USB is disconnected but you have started the native adb service in your device after each device reboot.

Some useful links:

[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

[How to make a capture screen app on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737992/how-to-make-a-capture-screen-app-on-android)

http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/UserGuide